# How to add search box inside select tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have used select HTML tag for dropdown selection now I want a search box inside select tag dropdown without using any third-party library is it possible with pure JS and CSS?

Don't want to use datalist tag from HTML.

Comment: A native `<select>` doesn't have this capability.  What you're looking to do is design your own custom component, with whatever markup and styling you like.

Answer (score -1):

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('select').selectize({
          sortField: 'text'
      });
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>
  <select id="select-state" placeholder="Pick a state...">
    <option value="">Select a state...</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP specifically stated: *"without using any third-party library"*  Additionally, using jQuery in a ReactJS application is a **famously** bad idea.